# Add scroll view for particular row in runtime in android?

Tags: android

In my tableview i need to add the scroll view for the particular rows . Is there any way to create like this in android?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create a `ScrollView` dynamically and add it in your table layout?
Something like that:

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
ScrollView.LayoutParams lp2 = new ScrollView.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
sv.setLayoutParams(lp2);
yourTable.addView(sv);
```